# What is "Resort-style living", "No Mello Roos" and "direct access garage"?

Tags: usa, accommodation, terminology, california, resorts

I read this description of a (rather expensive) house for sale in California, USA:

> Resort-style living in Baker Ranch community with No Mello Roos. This turnkey The Rowe Plan 1X townhome was built in 2017 and is located near the Vista Swim Club with a spacious courtyard featuring 3 upstairs bedrooms, 2.5 bathrooms, and a direct access 2-car garage with approx. 1,500sf of living space. This model perfect home welcomes you with an open floor plan, 9' feet ceilings, upgraded high-end laminate flooring, wall mounted flat panel TV pre-wired, and recessed lights in the great room and all of the rooms.

The neighbourhood looks cozy but not like a "resort" at all.

1. What would be a garage that is *not* "direct access"?
2. "Mello Roos" did have a Wikipedia entry, but I couldn't understand the description.
3. Resort-style living means what exactly? What makes that house such a "resort-style" house? Does somebody come and change my blankets for me every day and put a mint chocolate on the pillow? (I very strongly doubt that.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn’t clear how understanding a description of a house relates to travel

Comment: A garage without direct access could be a separate building, or (as in my case) below the house where you have to exit to the outside, up some stairs, and enter the house.  Probably plenty of other ways a garage is not direct access

Comment: Mello Roos is a California tax district where there is additional taxes allowed etc.  If this has no Mello Roos then there's not this extra tax. https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/melloroos.asp

Comment: Resort style living is where the house is in a community that has access to amenities like a club, gym, pools, tennis courts etc., like you would expect on a resort.

Comment: The above are just all my definition from experience and/or google

Comment: You better ask how much the monthly condo/HOA fees are for the "resort" amenities.

Answer (score 3):

1. One example of a garage that's not "direct access" is parking apartment style: a shared garage with assigned spaces, but you need to take communal elevators/stairs to reach your house, instead of having a direct entrance into your house.
2. [Mello-Roos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mello-Roos) is an additional property tax of sorts in California.
3. "Resort-style" is a pretty vague term, but here I presume it means that residents get access to shared facilities like pools, tennis courts, etc.